# SAGA algorithms don't work in QGIS 2.8

Tags: saga, qgis-2.8

when I have installed recently QGIS 2.8 and, since then, SAGA algorithms don't work. Apparently, the algorithm runs well (any error is showed while it is executing the algorithm), however,  there is not any result (shapefile or raster).

In the previous QGIS version (2.6), SAGA worked with any problem.

I've change the path of the SAGA folder to C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\saga.

In the info folder, in processing log window, appears this message:

**Salida de la consola de ejecución de SAGA
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\bin>set SAGA=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISVA~1/apps/saga
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISVA~1/apps/saga\modules
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\bin>PATH=PATH;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISVA~1/apps/saga;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISVA~1/apps/saga\modules
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\bin>saga_cmd shapes_polygons "Polygon Centroids" -POLYGONS "C:\VCT\process\stats\buffers\clkml2004_bff.shp" -METHOD          -CENTROIDS "C:\Users\JTRUJI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\644eb73b5d8a4c31b265c7759a4fbd4e\CENTROIDS.shp"
"saga_cmd" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\bin>exit**

'saga_cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

When I made the installation I used the QGIS 2.8 Standalone Installer Version. Furthermore, I've downloaded the latest version of SAGA (2.1.4) and I've copied it in the same folder of the former version (deleting the previous one).

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problems with SAGA (and GRASS) algorithms in QGIS 2.8.2 and figured out that the path to the SAGA (GRASS) functions was wrong. I still had the path to an older QGIS Chugiak installation ("C:/Program Files/QGIS Chugiak/apps/saga").
I changed the path under Processing > Providers > SAGA > SAGA folder manualy into "C:/Program Files/QGIS Wien/apps/saga" and the SAGA algorithms worked for me.