# Why is SAGA from the Processing Plugin not recognised?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, saga, qgis-processing, qgis-2.8

Similar to [SAGA algorithms don't work in QGIS 2.8](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148011) except that SAGA does not appear at all in the Processing Toolbox:

[image: Processing Toolbox]

As a check, I used the Python Console with the following code to see if any SAGA tools are available (which they're not):

```
import processing
processing.alglist()
```

I've installed QGIS 2.8.2 Wien via the **OSGeo4W Network Installer**, 64-bit and downloaded the latest version of the Processing Plugin (v2.9.3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add to the [earlier answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152765)...

You can find the field for the path here -

Processing > Options > Providers > SAGA > SAGA Folder:

[image: Processing options]

Comment: I have the 2.8.2 installation and the same problem. I can't solve it with this, as I have to select _a file_ instead of a folder into this specific location.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem, but I kept running into trouble re-pathing the SAGA folder. For some reason, the folder selection dialog kept forcing me to a file and inserted all of the folder separators as forward slashes:
C:/Program Files (x86)/QGIS 2.14/apps/saga_2.1.4_x64/saga_cmd.exe

I manually edited to C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS 2.14\apps\saga_2.1.4_x64, and that fixed my geoalgorithms.

(I rolled back to SAGA 2.1.4 because of this question: ["Unknown option 'CAREA'" in SAGA Catchment area algorithm for QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241439/unknown-option-carea-in-saga-catchment-area-algorithm-for-qgis). I don't think that was my problem, but everything I need is working now, so I'm afraid to change it back!)

Answer (score 1):

I simply had to change the SAGA path to where it was installed (which in my case was in the OSGeo4W directory):

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\saga
```

Now have the correct SAGA algorithms.

Comment: This needs clarification: SAGA path where? in QGIS? In SAGA? Or do you point to SAGA in your PATH environment variable? Please specify :)