# "Unknown option 'CAREA'" in SAGA Catchment area algorithm for QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, saga

18.7 version ans I try to use SAGA algorithm Catchment area and I take Unexpected error because that algorithm look easy.

I test with the different raster layer and the some error.

Maybe I have wrong define SAGA algorithms in QGIS?

Any idea?

here is the log message:

```
Algorithm Catchment area starting...
io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 0 -GRIDS "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\processing88768a29149b4908aa7eeeca546aeed2\9b66ada8123c4746bcf77335b5dc17b1\dem.sgrd" -FILES "C:\Users\username\Desktop\TWI_MODEL\dem.tif"
ta_hydrology "Flow Accumulation (Top-Down)" -ELEVATION "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\processing88768a29149b4908aa7eeeca546aeed2\9b66ada8123c4746bcf77335b5dc17b1\dem.sgrd" -METHOD 0 -CAREA "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\processing88768a29149b4908aa7eeeca546aeed2\ab16a4475bcf42a992e655c2d5f608eb\CAREA.sdat"

C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\bin>set SAGA=C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\apps\saga-ltr

C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\bin>PATH=C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg\shapely\DLLs;C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\apps\qgis\bin;C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\lib;C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\bin;C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\WBem;C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\apps\saga-ltr;C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\bin>saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 0 -GRIDS "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\processing88768a29149b4908aa7eeeca546aeed2\9b66ada8123c4746bcf77335b5dc17b1\dem.sgrd" -FILES "C:\Users\username\Desktop\TWI_MODEL\dem.tif"
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (32 bit)

____________________________
library path: C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\apps\saga-ltr\modules\
library name: io_gdal
library : GDAL/OGR
tool : Import Raster
author : O.Conrad (c) 2007 (A.Ringeler)
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________



Parameters


Grids: No objects
Files: "C:\Users\username\Desktop\TWI_MODEL\dem.tif"
Select from Multiple Bands:
Alphanumeric Sorting: yes
Transformation: yes
Resampling: Nearest Neighbour


loading: C:\Users\username\Desktop\TWI_MODEL\dem.tif



Driver: GTiff

Bands: 1

Rows: 2224

Columns: 3691


loading: dem





C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\bin>saga_cmd ta_hydrology "Flow Accumulation (Top-Down)" -ELEVATION "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\processing88768a29149b4908aa7eeeca546aeed2\9b66ada8123c4746bcf77335b5dc17b1\dem.sgrd" -METHOD 0 -CAREA "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\processing88768a29149b4908aa7eeeca546aeed2\ab16a4475bcf42a992e655c2d5f608eb\CAREA.sdat"
Unknown option 'CAREA'
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (32 bit)

____________________________
library path: C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\apps\saga-ltr\modules\
library name: ta_hydrology
library : Hydrology
tool : Flow Accumulation (Top-Down)
author : O.Conrad (c) 2001-2016, T.Grabs portions (c) 2010
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________


Usage: saga_cmd ta_hydrology 0 [-ELEVATION ] [-SINKROUTE ] [-WEIGHTS ] [-FLOW ] [-VAL_INPUT ] [-VAL_MEAN ] [-ACCU_MATERIAL ] [-ACCU_TARGET ] [-ACCU_TOTAL ] [-ACCU_LEFT ] [-ACCU_RIGHT ] [-STEP ] [-FLOW_UNIT ] [-FLOW_LENGTH ] [-LINEAR_VAL ] [-LINEAR_DIR ] [-METHOD ] [-LINEAR_DO ] [-LINEAR_MIN ] [-CONVERGENCE ] [-NO_NEGATIVES ] [-WEIGHT_LOSS ]
-ELEVATION: Elevation
Grid (input)
-SINKROUTE: Sink Routes
Grid (optional input)
-WEIGHTS: Weights
Grid (optional input)
-FLOW: Flow Accumulation
Grid (output)
-VAL_INPUT: Input for Mean over Catchment
Grid (optional input)
-VAL_MEAN: Mean over Catchment
Grid (output)
-ACCU_MATERIAL: Material for Accumulation
Grid (optional input)
-ACCU_TARGET: Accumulation Target
Grid (input)
-ACCU_TOTAL: Accumulated Material
Grid (optional output)
-ACCU_LEFT: Accumulated Material (Left Side)
Grid (optional output)
-ACCU_RIGHT: Accumulated Material (Right Side)
Grid (optional output)
-STEP: Step
Integer
Minimum: 1
Default: 1
-FLOW_UNIT: Flow Accumulation Unit
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] number of cells
[1] cell area
Default: 1
-FLOW_LENGTH: Flow Path Length
Grid (optional output)
-LINEAR_VAL: Linear Flow Threshold Grid
Grid (optional input)
-LINEAR_DIR: Channel Direction
Grid (optional input)
-METHOD: Method
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] Deterministic 8
[1] Rho 8
[2] Braunschweiger Reliefmodell
[3] Deterministic Infinity
[4] Multiple Flow Direction
[5] Multiple Triangular Flow Directon
[6] Multiple Maximum Downslope Gradient Based Flow Directon
Default: 4
-LINEAR_DO: Thresholded Linear Flow
Boolean
Default: 0
-LINEAR_MIN: Linear Flow Threshold
Integer
Default: 500
-CONVERGENCE: Convergence
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
Default: 1.100000
-NO_NEGATIVES: Prevent Negative Flow Accumulation
Boolean
Default: 1
-WEIGHT_LOSS: Loss through Negative Weights
Grid (optional output)

C:\Users\username\Desktop\qq\bin>exit
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers
```

here the error message :

The following layers were not correctly generated.

Catchment Area

You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm

Comment: I reproduced this `Unknown option 'CAREA'` error with SAGA 2.3.1 and 4.1.0. Is it okay for you to use older versions? SAGA versions up to 2.2.0 would work (2.1.4 was more stable for me). But I only tested 64-bit versions so it may be different from 32-bit cases.

Comment: @Kazuhito can i use old SAGA version in current QGIS version ?

Comment: Yes. You just need to download a zip file from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/?source=navbar) and extract it into C:/Program Files/QGIS2.18/apps folder, then set it as `SAGA folder` in Processing provider setting.

Comment: @Kazuhito yes but can i use in pyqgs ?because i work python

Comment: Please edit your OP to include additional information about your operating environment. Then you can expect more appropriate answers and comments.