# Error in catchment area calculation

Tags: qgis, saga, catchment-area

I downloaded a DEM based on the ASTER Global Digital Elevation Model (resolution 30 m; ASTGTM2_N42W009_dem.tif) from the Earth Explorer website (https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/). I am trying to calculate the catchment area in QGIS 2.18.10 with the SAGA (version 2.3.2) geoalgorithm "Catchment Area" available in QGIS toolbox. However, when I apply the algorithm, I get the following error (in bold):

**The following layers were not correctly generated.**

**Catchment Area**

**You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm**

Several SAGA algorithms yield the same error, while others work well apparently such as "clip raster with a polygon". I have been looking in the internet for potential solutions and I think it may be a mismatch between the QGIS and SAGA versions. I am running QGIS in Windows. Find below the log message that I obtain after running the "Catchment Area" algorithm:

```
Algorithm Catchment area starting...
ta_hydrology "Flow Accumulation (Top-Down)" -ELEVATION "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Temp\processingd042cd5855714f1aa9738be490723d02\22c5c81d5cb14560a14a1139b0c46106\ASTGTM2N42W009dem30m.sgrd" -METHOD 0 -CAREA "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Temp\processingd042cd5855714f1aa9738be490723d02\c9f6dd80b5f0406ba2b3170a06d7a314\CAREA.sdat"

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set SAGA=C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps\saga-ltr

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\shapely\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1\bin;{app};C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBem;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps\saga-ltr;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>saga_cmd ta_hydrology "Flow Accumulation (Top-Down)" -ELEVATION "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Temp\processingd042cd5855714f1aa9738be490723d02\22c5c81d5cb14560a14a1139b0c46106\ASTGTM2N42W009dem30m.sgrd" -METHOD 0 -CAREA "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Temp\processingd042cd5855714f1aa9738be490723d02\c9f6dd80b5f0406ba2b3170a06d7a314\CAREA.sdat"
Unknown option 'CAREA'
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (64 bit)

____________________________
library path: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\saga-ltr\modules\
library name: ta_hydrology
library : Hydrology
tool : Flow Accumulation (Top-Down)
author : O.Conrad (c) 2001-2016, T.Grabs portions (c) 2010
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________


Usage: saga_cmd ta_hydrology 0 [-ELEVATION ] [-SINKROUTE ] [-WEIGHTS ] [-FLOW ] [-VAL_INPUT ] [-VAL_MEAN ] [-ACCU_MATERIAL ] [-ACCU_TARGET ] [-ACCU_TOTAL ] [-ACCU_LEFT ] [-ACCU_RIGHT ] [-STEP ] [-FLOW_UNIT ] [-FLOW_LENGTH ] [-LINEAR_VAL ] [-LINEAR_DIR ] [-METHOD ] [-LINEAR_DO ] [-LINEAR_MIN ] [-CONVERGENCE ] [-NO_NEGATIVES ] [-WEIGHT_LOSS ]
-ELEVATION: Elevation
Grid (input)
-SINKROUTE: Sink Routes
Grid (optional input)
-WEIGHTS: Weights
Grid (optional input)
-FLOW: Flow Accumulation
Grid (output)
-VAL_INPUT: Input for Mean over Catchment
Grid (optional input)
-VAL_MEAN: Mean over Catchment
Grid (output)
-ACCU_MATERIAL: Material for Accumulation
Grid (optional input)
-ACCU_TARGET: Accumulation Target
Grid (input)
-ACCU_TOTAL: Accumulated Material
Grid (optional output)
-ACCU_LEFT: Accumulated Material (Left Side)
Grid (optional output)
-ACCU_RIGHT: Accumulated Material (Right Side)
Grid (optional output)
-STEP: Step
Integer
Minimum: 1
Default: 1
-FLOW_UNIT: Flow Accumulation Unit
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] number of cells
[1] cell area
Default: 1
-FLOW_LENGTH: Flow Path Length
Grid (optional output)
-LINEAR_VAL: Linear Flow Threshold Grid
Grid (optional input)
-LINEAR_DIR: Channel Direction
Grid (optional input)
-METHOD: Method
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] Deterministic 8
[1] Rho 8
[2] Braunschweiger Reliefmodell
[3] Deterministic Infinity
[4] Multiple Flow Direction
[5] Multiple Triangular Flow Directon
[6] Multiple Maximum Downslope Gradient Based Flow Directon
Default: 4
-LINEAR_DO: Thresholded Linear Flow
Boolean
Default: 0
-LINEAR_MIN: Linear Flow Threshold
Integer
Default: 500
-CONVERGENCE: Convergence
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
Default: 1.100000
-NO_NEGATIVES: Prevent Negative Flow Accumulation
Boolean
Default: 1
-WEIGHT_LOSS: Loss through Negative Weights
Grid (optional output)

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>exit
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers

The following layers were not correctly generated.
Catchment Area
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorit
```

**EDIT**: Following Kazuhito's comment, I installed SAGA 2.1.4 and the algorithm produced a raster layer. However, I am not sure if the algorithm ran properly because during the process, some errors were identified because the algorithm was not finding specific libraries. Despite this, I installed the most recent release of QGIS (2.18.13), which has incorporated SAGA 2.3.2, and apparently the algorithm "Catchment area" works well without any specific errors appearing in the log.

Comment: I share the same view with you that this is due to SAGA version. Could you try an older one, say SAGA 2.1.4? [“Unknown option 'CAREA'” in SAGA Catchment area algorithm for QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241439/unknown-option-carea-in-saga-catchment-area-algorithm-for-qgis)

Comment: Thanks André Lourenço, that's great. I will try QGIS 2.18.13 myself. By the way will you post your edit (actually solved the issue), as answer and accept it for our future reference?

Comment: André Lourenço QGIS2.18.13 does work!

Comment: Yes, I can post it as an answer. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

Following Kazuhito's comment, I installed SAGA 2.1.4 and the algorithm produced a raster layer. However, I am not sure if the algorithm ran properly because during the process, some errors were identified because the algorithm was not finding specific libraries. Despite this, I installed the most recent release of QGIS (2.18.13), which has incorporated SAGA 2.3.2, and apparently the algorithm "Catchment area" works well without any specific errors appearing in the log.