# Watershed delineation by using QGIS with ifsar dtm 5m resolution of grid

Tags: qgis, watershed

I had some problems during running the channel and drainage basin with an IFSAR DTM, 5m resolution. I followed these steps, according to the guidance from website of QGIS:

1. I reprojected the DTM to my CRS.
2. I ran the fill sink(wang & liu).
3. I generated the strahler order and used raster calculator to find the stream line.

However, when I finished the process, I found that the stream line was not continuous. Under this situation, I continued to run extension of channel and drainage basin. For the result the channel and the drainage basin that I generated were blank.

May I know whether the QGIS software is sufficient to run the watershed delineation with ifsar dtm 5m resolution of grid or not?

Comment: Can you add a direct link to the documentation you used? For example, [this tutorial](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/processing/hydro.html) uses a tool called `Channel Network` to find stream lines instead of the strahler order and raster calculator.

Comment: I suggest you to go for the GRASS commands `r.watershed` and `r.water.outlet`. Have a look to this Q&A https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257355/how-to-delineate-watersheds-in-qgis